Inconsistent results in rendering light tree motion blur
Currently I'm working on kinda heavy car animation project (2.2GB)
I'm using motion blur, cycles, light tree, 1024 samples, denoise. (Rest default).
On some frames (65/300, 21.(6)% ) there are issues with light. Some objects behave like they don't receive light from certain lights.
When I turn off light tree, there are no issues with that, but the lighting is little bit different. Same with motion blur.
I don't want to turn off motion blur.
Is there a way to render animation using light tree so I don't have bugs?
I can't render those frames without this bug.

Without light tree (slightly different lighting, couses blinking)

With light tree with bug

With light tree without bug next frame
Please help
